# Top Right Legend Position for a C3 chart?

Tags: c3.js

Is there a way to position the legend in 'top right' for c3 charts?

The current options appear to only allow 'bottom' and 'right'. I've noticed there is a 'Custom Legend Option'. However, I wanted to check before proceeding down this path.

Thanks

Comment: Just implemented the [Custom Legend Option](http://c3js.org/samples/legend_custom.html), and it allowed me to position (and style) the legend any way I want

Answer (score 29):

I have a same issue. So I spent many time to find the solution. And Finally, I got the solution. Here is the solution.

## Document

C3 Document is not bad, but some example is incomplete. **Position of legend** is one of them.

[The example](http://c3js.org/samples/legend_position.html) show position of legend can be located in only `bottom, right and inset`. That's all. But in the [document](http://c3js.org/reference.html), you can find more possibility.

Look at the [c3.legend.position](http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-position) in the document. The document says again legend can be located in only `bottom, right and inset`. But don't be disappointed. Look at the below item, [c3.legend.inset](http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-inset).
And today, that item will save our time.

## Code

First of all, look at the example.

```js
legend: {
  inset: {
    anchor: 'top-right'
    x: 20,
    y: 10,
    step: 2
  }
}
```

You see it? That's a `top-right` you want. And code works wonderfully. If you change `anchor`, the position of legend'll be changed. And you can adjust coordinates with `x` and `y`. And `step` may be adjust length of legend. If you increase it, then legend'll be longer. But it's my guess. Please someone explain more about it.

## Example

Here is my example.

[image: c3.legend.inset example]

```js
var appActivityChart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        //...
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'inset',
        inset: {
            anchor: 'top-right',
            x: 250,
            y: 50,
            step: 5
        }
    }
});
```

---

I hope C3 add or refer about [c3.legend.inset](http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-inset). [Current example](http://c3js.org/samples/legend_position.html) is too complicated. Until that time I hope this answer can save your time. Have great coding.

Comment: Great answer. In [the example](http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-inset) it is not clear that `position: 'inset'` is required. Your answer makes that clear here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I have same question and found next solution to place legend above chart:

```
legend: {
    position: 'inset',
    inset: {
        anchor: 'top-left',
        x: 20,
        y: -40,
        step: 1
    }
},
padding: {
    top: 40
}
```

And legend will not cover chart.

Answer (score 4):

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    },
     legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'inset',
        inset: {
            anchor: 'top-right',
            x:undefined,
            y: undefined,
            step: undefined
        }
    }
});
```

Replaced undefined in x,y and step . The legend is display on top right.

Answer (score 0):

```
  inset: {
            anchor: 'top-right',
            x: 250,
            y: 50,
            step: 5
        }
```

Change to

```
  inset: {
            anchor: 'top-right'
        }
```